# Animating a div up and down repeatedly

Tags: jquery, animation

I would like to have a div that moves up and down repeatedly using jquery. In other words, the div starts at the top of some location, moves down and then moves back up and repeats this, in about a 1 second interval from going from top to bottom and 1 second back to the top. There's the slideUp and slideDown as well as animate methods but I'm not sure how to accomplish this since it needs to be in an endless loop and in javascript you must avoid such loops.

Comment: can you prepare a jsfiddle demo of what you want

Comment: How about `setInterval`? It's used to do the same action every X milliseconds. You use a variable like `isDown`, a boolean, which you alternate between true and false, each time animating your block up and down, and then a `switch` or a simple `if` to slide it up if it's down, and down if it's up.

Comment: callbacks should alleviate the need for a boolean flag

Comment: setInterval has its own timer and if I use slideUp/slideDown or animate, they use their own timers and I believe it is possible for the two to get out of sync.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

jQuery's animate logic can safely be called with callbacks or chained together without using setTimeout/setInterval:

Something like this should work just fine for you

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2PdRE/1/)

```
function loop() {
    $('.bouncer').animate({'top': '500'}, {
        duration: 1000, 
        complete: function() {
            $('.bouncer').animate({top: 0}, {
                duration: 1000, 
                complete: loop});
        }});
}
loop();
```

Comment: That is so frikken cool! That seems to rule out using slideUp/slideDown.

Comment: Updated demo to show outer loop exiting just in case there were any doubts.

Comment: thanks! please mind that you are missing some single quotes on the complete function.

Answer (score 0):

use setInterval, see here: 
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

so try this

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $('#thediv').slideUp('500', function() {
            $('#thediv').slideDown('500');
        });
    }, 1000);
});
```

HTML

```
<div id='thediv' style='width:100px;height:200px;border:1px solid black;'>
Div Contents
</div>
```

you may need to tweak the timings (which are in miliseconds)

Comment: I thought about that, but you are using a setInterval that contains a timer interval in addition to a separate animation time of 500 ms. That's not good because the two could essentially get out of sync.

Comment: without an (agreeably) bad infinite loop I don't see doing this without setinterval

Comment: Oh calling loop on callback that makes sense. Neat.