# Repeating a nested animation in jQuery

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I have an animation (a `div` with a background image) which has another animation as callback.

A car drives from right to left, then turns and drives back. all with some delay. I want the whole animation run again infinite times.

**Here is the code:**

```
var tempoPolente = 10000;
var viewport = $(window).width() + 300;

// Animation 
var polenteAnim = function() { 
    $("#polente").removeClass('flip').animate({"right": "+="+viewport}, tempoPolente, 'linear',
            function() {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $("#polente").addClass("flip").animate({"right": "-="+viewport}, tempoPolente, 'linear');
                }, 1000);
    });
};
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Animating a div up and down repeatedly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18349108/animating-a-div-up-and-down-repeatedly)

Answer (score 1):

Modifying the [linked example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18349108/animating-a-div-up-and-down-repeatedly) slightly, you can introduce delays into your animation using [$.delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay/):

This is the simplest form, but does introduce a delay at the start of the animation:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2PdRE/3/)

```
function loop() {
    $('.bouncer').delay(1000)
                 .animate({'top': '500'}, 1000)
                 .delay(1000)
                 .animate({top: 0}, 1000, loop);
}
loop();
```

To remove that delay, replace the last completion callback with a setTimeout and remove the initial delay:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2PdRE/5/)

```
function loop() {
    $('.bouncer').animate({'top': '500'}, 1000)
                 .delay(1000)
                 .animate({top: 0}, 1000, function() {
                     setTimeout(loop, 1000);
                 });
}
loop();
```

**Your Function** modified to use this style would look something like:

```
var polenteAnim = function() { 
    $("#polente").removeClass('flip')
                 .animate({"right": "+="+viewport}, tempoPolente, 'linear')
                 .delay(1000)
                 .addClass("flip")
                 .animate({"right": "-="+viewport}, tempoPolente, 'linear', function() {
                     setTimeout(polenteAnim, 1000);
                 });
};
```

If you prefer to leave your animation function intact, you can simply call the entry point again on completion of the internal animation:

```
var polenteAnim = function() { 
    $("#polente").removeClass('flip').animate({"right": "+="+viewport}, tempoPolente, 'linear',
            function() {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    // Add polente as the completion callback here...
                    $("#polente").addClass("flip").animate({"right": "-=" + viewport}, tempoPolente, 'linear', function () {
                        setTimeout(polenteAnim, 1000);
                    });
                }, 1000);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple **`recursion`** is enough to do infinite loops.

Try this.

```
var tempoPolente = 10000;
var viewport = $(window).width() + 300;

// Animation 
var polenteAnim = function() { 
    $("#polente").removeClass('flip').animate({"right": "+="+viewport}, tempoPolente, 'linear',
            function() {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $("#polente").addClass("flip").animate({"right": "-="+viewport}, tempoPolente, 'linear');
                }, 1000);
    });
polenteAnim();  //recursion
};
```