# Detach event working only the first time with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, scroll

I have a timeline which is showing a different content depending on the selected date. Date can be selected either by clicking on the timeline, either scrolling with mouse wheel.
I have some animations attached to each content, in order to have a fade out/fade in effect of the different content elements, and for this I'm using nested animations, with callbacks.

What I'm not able to do, is to wait for the previous animation to end, before the next one begins, if scrolling fastly. 
Or, better, I detach the scrolling event at the beginning of the animation function, and re-attach it, as a callback of the last `animate` function call: this works only the first time, but not with subsequent scrolls.

Any idea?

**Function detecting scroll:**

```
      //detect mouse scrolling and determine the direction
        function detectScroll() {
            $('.events-content').first().bind('mousewheel', function (e) {
                var delta = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;
                if (delta > 0) {
                    jumpToEvent('prev');
                } else {
                    jumpToEvent('next');
                }
            });

            //firefox
            $('.events-content').first().on('DOMMouseScroll', function (e) {
                var delta = e.originalEvent.detail;
                if (delta < 0) {
                    jumpToEvent('prev');
                } else if (delta > 0) {
                    jumpToEvent('next');
                }
            });
        }
```

**Function detatching scrolling**

```
function detachScroll(){
            console.log('detach');
            $('.events-content').first().unbind('mousewheel');
            $('.events-content').first().off('DOMMouseScroll');
        }
```

**Function with animations, called by jumpToEvent function, that choose the correct content to show:**

```
 //display correct content depending on the selected date
function updateVisibleContent(event, eventsContent) {

    var visibleContent = ...., selectedContent =....;

    detachScroll();

    visibleContent.find('....').each(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            opacity: 0 //hide current content
        }, 600, function () { 

            visibleContent.removeClass('selected');
            selectedContent.attr('class', 'selected'); 

            //now show the next content, with 3 subsequent steps (Showing only one for the sake of readability)
            selectedContent.find('...').first().animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, 500, function () {
                     detectScroll();
            });            
        });
    });     
}
```

Comment: What about just using `.stop()` to stop old animations?

Comment: did you try to register your animation function with document ready function to allow the animation complete and start new one when page delegate any event you want  ?

Comment: @Deckerz I have tried to use .stop(), at the beginning of the animation function,instead of the detach(), but i have a similar behavior, it works the first time, then if i keep scrolling fast, the next content is shown all together. By the way it's not the behavior I would like to have, I'd prefer to "wait" for the content to be fully shown. Any clue?

Comment: @moathnaji mmm not sure to understand what you mean.

Comment: Try `$(this).stop().animate(//reset of you function here)` in the updatevisibleContent. Basically try adding stop everywhere before .animate()

Comment: @sissy i mean that we can register the event's we want in the ready function to make sure that event and DOM finish rendering then the calls of events will go smoothly what do you think ?

Comment: @Deckerz I modified the call to .stop() with .stop(true, false) and it works quite nicely. I also added your advice to put it everywhere else, and the result is almost the same. It is not exactly the behavior I was thinking, but it is satisfactory. If you put your comment as an answer, and do not get any better answer, I will accept yours. I still have a problem with first and last event, if i scoll fastly it somehow goes out of range. i will try to put a check on boundaries of dates. thank you.

Comment: @moathnaji I think this will not solve the problem of enabling the next animation before the previous has finished. but thank you for your help

Comment: @sissy if you are sure sorry for that but if you are not give it a chance ,  thank you for replay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `.stop()` before every animate call, this ensures that there is no pending/ongoing animation when calling the next animation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried jQuery [deferred-object](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/), it is a way of waiting on async functions to finish.

```
function doAnimations(domElement, i) {
  var dfd = jQuery.Deferred();

  $(domElement[i]).animate({
    //do somthing
  }, 600, function() {
    dfd.resolve
  })

  return dfd.promise();
}

//And this is how you can itterate tru items
(function rec(i){
    if(i >= numbers of itterations) {
    console.log('End')
    return false
  }

  doAnimations(domElement, i).done(function(){
    rec(++i)
  })
})(0)
```

Comment: I have seen a similar solution, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18360963/repeating-a-nested-animation-in-jquery here, but i thought it was not solving my problem. I will give it a try, if I don't get my example working, but for now it seems fine.