# Animating an image vertically - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I have been trying to get an image to appear to be floating by using jQuery to animate it vertically. After doing some digging I came across this thread: [Animating a div up and down repeatedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18349108/animating-a-div-up-and-down-repeatedly)
which has exactly what I need. After applying the code to my website, I still can't figure out why the image isn't behaving like the example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2PdRE/1/).
Here is the code I have thus far.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type ="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>  

    <!-- Checking to see if running properly
    <script>
    window.onload = function() {
        if (window.jQuery) {  
            // jQuery is loaded  
            alert("Yeah!");
        } else {
            // jQuery is not loaded
            alert("Doesn't Work");
        }
    }
    </script> -->
</head>

<body>

<table id="wrapper">
  <tr>
    <td><img src="PixelBuddah.png" class="bouncer" alt="PixelBuddah" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<footer>
    <p>...</p>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
html, body, #wrapper {
   height:100%;
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   border: 0;
}
#wrapper td {
   vertical-align: middle;
   text-align: center;
}

body {
    background-color: #F5E9D3;
}

footer {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    margin: auto;
    margin-right: 1.2em;
    font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

Javascript

```
function loop() {
$('.bouncer').animate({'top': '500'}, {
    duration: 1000, 
    complete: function() {
        $('.bouncer').animate({top: 0}, {
            duration: 1000, 
            complete: loop});
    }});

$('<div/>').text('exiting loop').appendTo($('.results'));
}
loop();
```

I'm still really new to this, so any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Your CSS is missing this crucial rule `.bouncer { position: absolute; }` (You're animating the style's `top` attribute, which is ignored unless the position isn't the default)

Comment: @ChrisG I added this CSS, but it only un-centered the img. I still can't get it to animate. Instead of centering it using a table, would using some other method to get it to the very center of the browser window work better maybe?

Comment: You can CSS's flexbox rules. But that's a different question. Your code works when I add the rule: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/3fuejfjp/ (also note that you've added two versions of jQuery in your `<head>`)

Comment: @ChrisG I've cleared out one of the jquery links in my <head> and I've doubled checked all the code. But for whatever reason, when I open the index.html file in chrome I'm just not getting that animation. I can't seem to find out what's preventing it from running.

Comment: Did you check the browser console for errors? Press F12

Comment: Yeah, the console isn't showing anything. Page loads up and it remains blank. I thought maybe it's a problem with my browser, but it's not doing anything when I load it up in firefox, either.

Comment: @ChrisG I got it!
After browsing through more forums, the reason was that I was putting my code above the elements that it operates on and not delaying it using a "ready" event. But JSfiddle puts the JavaScript in an onload handler which delays it. So I just moved my code from script.js to the html document, near the end of the page to see if that was the problem and it started working. 
So now I just need to figure out how to make it a "ready" event in script.js so I can keep my javascript separate from my HTML.

Comment: Ah, I see. Wrap your code in `$(document).ready(function () {` and `});`

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't get the code to format. I tried 'code'
But I tried wrapping my JavaScript like
    
    '$(document).ready(function loop() {
       The rest of my code(Can't figure out how to get it to format)

    });
 
    loop();'
    

But that didn't seem to work, am I wrapping it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are changing the position of the image, you need to add the position property to the CSS of your image. Note the CSS for img tag

```js
function loop() {
$('.bouncer').animate({'top': '500'}, {
    duration: 1000, 
    complete: function() {
        $('.bouncer').animate({top: 0}, {
            duration: 1000, 
            complete: loop});
    }});

$('<div/>').text('exiting loop').appendTo($('.results'));
}
loop();
```

```css
html, body, #wrapper {
   height:100%;
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   border: 0;
}
#wrapper td {
   vertical-align: middle;
   text-align: center;
}

body {
    background-color: #F5E9D3;
}

footer {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    margin: auto;
    margin-right: 1.2em;
    font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<table id="wrapper">
  <tr>
    <td><img src="PixelBuddah.png" class="bouncer" alt="PixelBuddah" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<footer>
    <p>...</p>
</footer>

</body>
```